# Get single item by key in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following that I am using in my Vue template.

```
0: { id:1, name:test1}
1: { id:2, name:test2}
2: { id:3, name:test3}
```

Inside my Vue template I have the following which works

```
<div v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="product.id">
```

This works great for the loop but how can I get a single item from `products` by key. In this example I want only `1: { id:2, name:test2}`

I tried `products[0].name` but that did not work.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work ?

Comment: If I use {{ products[1] }}, it prints { "id": 2, "name": "test2"}. But if I try to access the {{ products[1].name }} or products[1]["name"], I get an error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: I guess you load `products` dynamically, at some point your `products` has not been loaded yet which gives the error. Try `products[1]?.name` ?

Comment: Perfect, using products[1]?.name works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <div v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="`product-${index}`">
```